# SSRS Dynamically setting table position/location

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I see in Report Builder / design mode, there is a Position and Location property that allows you to set how far from the top or left the table should appear.

My question is, is there a way to set 2 or more tables in the same location (ie top of the page 0 from top, 0 from left) without having them stacked on top of each other in design mode / report builder?

Is there a way to dynamically set that position property?

For instance, here is a sketch of a report in report builder:

```
top of page
---------------------------
Table 1 (hide)            |
                          |
                          |
                          |
Table 2 (show at top)     |
                          |
                          |
                          |
                          |
                          |
                          |
                          |
---------------------------
```

bottom of page

Answer (score 4):

The location properties for Tablix members are not expression based. However, you can show/hide objects within a report based on a parameter, and this can affect the position of other report items. A simple example:

A report with a **Header**, two **Tablix** members and one parameter, `HideTable`:

[image]

The `Hidden` property for the top **Tablix** is set to `=Parameters!HideTable.Value`, i.e. the parameter toggles whether it's displayed. With this setup and layout, SSRS automatically shifts the second **Tablix** to the top of the report **Body** when the first **Tablix** is hidden. See below:

[image]

[image]

So it's not quite a dynamic location, but by using other features you can achieve the same functionality as above.

Answer (score 1):

In Addition to Answer mentioned by Ian Preston, If Table 1 Does not have data, then we need  write as follows:

```
=Parameters!HideTable.Value or IIF(countrows("Tablix1")<1,True,False)
```

Here, **Tablix1** is First tablix name
So that header would not appear in case of data unavailability in Table1